# App is crashing on iPad 3 but not on iPad 2 - Crash Log

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, crash

I have an app which is running perfectly on the iPad2, but has been rejected by Apple due to crashing on the iPad 3.

I have symbolicated the crash log and narrowed the crash down to the method below.

```
-(void)mergeTwoVideos {

//AVExport (oddly) has a problem with file name already existing - therefore check if file already exists and delete if needed.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FinishedVideo.mov"];

if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writablePath]){ 
    NSLog(@"Problem - file already exists");
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writablePath error:NULL];
}
else{ 
    NSLog(@"No Problem - New File");
}

//Instantiate AVMutable Composition.

CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

AVURLAsset* a_videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: [assetURLArray objectForKey:kIntroVideo] options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

CMTimeRange a_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,a_videoAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];


[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:a_timeRange ofTrack:[[a_videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, a_timeRange.duration);

AVURLAsset* b_videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: [assetURLArray objectForKey:kMainVideo] options:nil];

CMTimeRange b_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, b_videoAsset.duration);
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:b_timeRange ofTrack:[[b_videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:b_timeRange ofTrack:[[b_videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

nextClipStartTime = CMTimeAdd(nextClipStartTime, b_videoAsset.duration);

AVURLAsset* c_videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL: [assetURLArray objectForKey:kIntroVideo] options:nil];
CMTimeRange c_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, c_videoAsset.duration);
[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:c_timeRange ofTrack:[[c_videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];

NSString *exportVideoPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/FinishedVideo.mov"];

NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportVideoPath];
exportSession.outputURL = exportURL;
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
            NSLog (@"FAIL");
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
            NSLog (@"SUCCESS");
            [exportSession release];
            [self finishMergingProcess];
}
};
 }];
```

}

The symbolicated crash log is as follows :

```
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36d4832c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3173a208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31733298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36c10f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36c0e346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3682b350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36c0e3be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36c0e44a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36c0f798 __cxa_throw + 116
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3682b290 objc_exception_throw + 88
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31f1f9d4 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 264
11  AppName                         0x00023d6e -[ViewController mergeTwoVideos]     (ViewController.m:746)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x31eb4c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x31eb7810 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x316f5df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x316f5cc8 start_wqthread + 0
```

Can anybody offer any insight into what is causing this crash on iPad 3? The frustrating thing is that I don't own an iPad3 to test myself, so appreciate any help.

Thank you !

Comment: Which is line 746? Is there any crash message supplied?

Comment: [a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:a_timeRange ofTrack:[[a_videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];

Comment: Crash message is Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to grab an object by index from an NSArray where the array doesn't have that number of elements.

Given the # of `objectAtIndex:0` calls you have where you don't check to see if the array is empty or nil first, any one of those is likely the problem.

Considering that you have no validation in the code to make sure the URLs are correct, that the assets are being loaded, or that the assets of the bits and pieces expected, there are dozens of potential points of failure in that code.

You need to modify the code to be defensive throughout;  check for nil, check for empty arrays, check for failure to load URLs, etc...